# Компиляция файлов python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Я написал панель управления чат-ботами и мне надо скомпилировать несколько файлов через auto-py-to-exe(pyinstaller) так, чтобы они работали друг с другом. Если быть точнее, то у меня имеется скрипт, который управляет веб-сервером, файл в котором запускаются все служебные процессы и шаблоны для создания чат-ботов.

При создании чат-бота создается файл в корневом каталоге приложения (там где файл main.py)

Все файлы .py обращаются к БД (data.db) и папке bots (папка с файлами чат-ботов)

**Моя проблема именно в том, что при компиляция файла main.py создается папка _internal со всеми нужными файлами и при компиляции файлов шаблонов и служебного скрипта тоже создается эта папка. Но при работе main.exe берет все файлы из папки _internal и создает их там, а мне надо, чтобы файлы создавались в одной папке с main.exe**

1. Структура проекта

main.py - основной файл с
веб-сервером

obnl.py - служебный файл с задачами типа свода статистики и создания резервных копий

bots - папка с файлами для чат-ботов

new-bot - шаблоны

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Папка с шаблнами чат-ботов

[image: Папка с шаблнами чат-ботов]

Также во всех скриптах у меня прописан метод определения родительского каталога: `OS_PATH = os.path.split(__file__)[0]`, но путь все равно определяется в папке _internal

Если быть короче, то мне нужно сделать так, чтобы main.exe брал и создавал все файлы в родительской папке, а не _internal

Comment: Если в каждом модуле делать, то путь будет относительно каждого модуля и считаться. Exe файл возможно имеет смысл находить по `sys.argv[0]` - при запуске через скрипт это будет путь интерпретатора Python, после "компиляции" - путь к exe файлу, который у вас main.exe видимо.